# Adding Authorization Policies to ASP.Net Core 3.0 with F#

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-3.0, authorize-attribute

I know that I am just missing something silly here, but I haven't done this in F# before so having just a bit of trouble.

I am trying to test using policies with an api built in ASP.Net Core 3 with F#.  Here is my configuration code in Startup.fs for MVC and Authorization from the ConfigureServices method:

```
        controllerBuilder.AddMvcOptions(fun config ->
            let genPolicy = (new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(genPolicy))
            )|> ignore
        services.AddResponseCaching() |> ignore

        services.AddAuthorization(fun config ->
            let driverPolicy = (new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()).RequireClaim("role",["Driver"]).Build()
            let dispatcherPolicy = (new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()).RequireClaim("role",["Dispatcher"]).Build()
            let adminPolicy = (new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()).RequireClaim("role",["Admin"]).Build()
            config.AddPolicy("Driver",driverPolicy)
            config.AddPolicy("Dispatcher",dispatcherPolicy)
            config.AddPolicy("Admin",adminPolicy)) |> ignore
```

And of course in the configure method I have the following:

```
app.UseAuthorization() |> ignore
```

Now my expectation is that I would be able to apply these policies via attributes at the conroller level like so:

```
[<ApiController>]
[<Authorize(Policy = "Driver")>]
[<Route("api"+CollectionDriverHateoas.myActiveRouteStopsRoot)>]
type MyActiveRouteStopsController private () =
    inherit ControllerBase()

    new (configuration: IConfiguration, logger : ILogger<MyActiveRouteStopsController>) as this =
        MyActiveRouteStopsController() then
        this._configuration <- configuration

     member val private _configuration : IConfiguration = null with get, set

     member private this.getConnStr = this._configuration.getDbConnection()
```

However... This is not working as expected currently, It is rejecting users with the desired role. Here is part of the payload from the JWT that was rejected. You can see that it has the claim for role with a value of Driver.

```
{
  "userName": "rhicks",
  "isInternal": "True",
  "tokenId": "6f074456-d80e-4dce-b689-49d55b989561",
  "role": "Driver"
}
```

I am about to do a quick test with the same code in C# to see if I am just missing a step, but any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

So after setting up a custom requirement it became clear what is going on here. If you add a claim with the name **'role'** it will be replaced with **'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role'**. To avoid the issue in general just use the ClaimTypes provided for when possible...